# Does a fully dynamic host-guest cluster system already exist?

Tags: networking

I'm looking for existing literature on systems where the host as well as the guests are all dynamic; any device might drop out at any moment, or reconnect.

Use case: ad-hoc mobile compute-farms where the mobile devices consume data from attached sensors and carry out tasks delegated to them by the host(s). The host (task-broker) itself might change over the course of time, and the devices are not necessarily homogeneous.

I couldn't think of any networks where both the host and the guests were dynamic and could change over time.

Comment: What you describe resembles a P2P network or a botnet. Having the control devices be mobile isn’t an issue per se, the issue is how do new devices “find” the others, and for that usually you’ll need something that is fixed, though through dynamic DNS this could be relatively mobile. You need to take into account the caching time of DNS records so having multiple records and trying multiple addresses to find the coordinator would probably help.

Comment: Note that due to NAT traversal problems you’ll need at least some of the hosts in the network to not be behind a NAT (or have port forwarding or something similar set up).

Comment: See if you can use Avahi or Bonjour.